# When editing Lisp code, can emacs be configured to display each nested level of parentheses in a different color?

Tags: emacs, lisp

In other words, a block of code like this:

```
(setq initial-major-mode
  (lambda ()
    (text-mode)
    (font-lock-mode)
    ))
```

... would come out looking like something like this:

[image]

If something like this already exists, what is it? And if it doesn't exist, how should I go about writing it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [mwe-color-box.el](http://www.foldr.org/~michaelw/emacs/mwe-color-box.el)

Answer (score 4):

There is the package [rainbow-delimiters](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters), which doesn't do exactly what you want, but does just colorize the parentheses - which is a nice subset and allows you to still see the other syntax highlighting provided by the major mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you need this to help editing, then I suggest turning on coloring the *innermost* sexp which contains the cursor with a different background color. At least I'm used to this and it is sufficient.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to turn that feature on?

Answer (score 2):

http://nschum.de/src/emacs/highlight-parentheses/ lets you highlight just the parentheses.